# Jquery, addclass to created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am using jQuery to dynamically build the column header for fullcalendar.js.  This code is working but I want to be able to add a class name to each of the  elements.

```
function buildDateColumnHeader(theDate) {
    var container = document.createElement('div');
    var DDD = document.createElement('span');
    var ddMMM = document.createElement('span');
    DD.textContent = theDate.format('DD').toUpperCase();
    ddd.textContent = theDate.format('ddd');
    container.appendChild(DD);
    container.appendChild(ddd);

    return container;
}
```

I have tried the following and they produce errors:

```
DDD.classname = "ds-header-day";

var DDD = document.createElement('span').addClass('ds-header-day');
```

This is probably easy for a jquery savvy person.

Comment: `DDD.addClass('ds-header-day');` ?

Comment: that doesnt work either

Comment: `they produce errors` And they are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your statement, hope that is not causing problems

It should be `DDD.className='yourclass'`